# why @use in sass imports code into a stylesheet which @use isn't used directly?

Tags: css, sass

I'm implementing a project and based on my knowledge `@use` is supposed to import code only to the stylesheet which we have used `@use` not any other stylesheet.

***sass document:***

***Members (variables, functions, and mixins) loaded with @use are only visible in the stylesheet that loads them. Other stylesheets will need to write their own @use rules if they also want to access them.***

so I have `_b.scss` which is the main file for my sass that compiles it to css, then I got `a.scss` which is the file I imported `_b.scss` in it via `@use`, after that, I have `project.scss` which I have imported `a.scss` in it, so based on this hierarchy, `_b.scss` shouldn't be accessible in `project.scss` but when I compile `project.scss` into css, in my css file I have compiled scss code from `_b.scss`(however if I write something like `@debug map-get($colors."red")` in `project.scss` in throws an error),so why this is happeng?

***FYI***: I'm using `gulp` for compiling, purging and watching my scss and css.

```
//file hierarchy

index.html
gulpfile.js
a.scss
_b.scss
project
  project.scss
css
  project.css
```

```
//index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/project.css">
<title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="bg-red">hey</div>
<div class="bg-purple">hey</div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
//_b.scss

 $colors:(
 "red":red,
 "blue":blue,
 "green":green,
 "yellow":yellow,
 "brown":brown,
 "purple":purple
 );

 @each $key,$val in $colors{
 .bg-#{$key}{
 background: $val;
 }  
 }
```

```
//a.scss

@use "b";
```

```
//project.scss

@use "../a";
```

```
//project.css

.bg-red {
background: red;
}

.bg-purple {
background: purple;
}
```

```
//gulpfile.js

const { src, dest, watch, series } = require('gulp')
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'))
const purgecss = require('gulp-purgecss')

function buildStyles() {
return src('project/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({}))
    .pipe(purgecss({ content: ['*.html'] }))
    .pipe(dest('css'))
}

function watchTask() {
watch(['project/*.scss', '*.html'], buildStyles)
}

exports.default = series(buildStyles, watchTask)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your own pull quote (emphasis mine):

> **Members (variables, functions, and mixins)** loaded with @use are only visible in the stylesheet that loads them.

Note how this does not include **style rules**. Style rules are still "loaded" into the resulting stylesheet, as per [the documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use/):

> Any styles loaded this way will be included exactly once in the compiled CSS output […]

So `@use` is used to isolate what **members** (variables, functions, and mixins) are visible, while still outputting style rules.